# select a value with special characters

Tags: r, excel

1. How can I select a value which begins with `"-"` and ends with `"*"`?
2. How can I select a value which doesn't begin with `"-"` but ends with `"*"`?

For example, my data looks like this way:

```
 0.5, -0.4*, 1.8*, 2.5**, 0.8
```

3. My data in excel contains equations. when I import the data to R, how can I only import value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str_match()` or `gsub()` (with slightly different syntax).

```
library(stringr)

data = c("0.5", "-0.4*","1.8*", "2.5**", "0.8","-0.5")

#1. Matched all starting with - and ending without a star
str_match(data,"^-[0-9\\.]+[^\\*]$")

#2. Meches all not starting with - but ending with a star
str_match(data,"^[^-][0-9\\.]+\\*$")
```

2. You can save as a csv file, and read it into R.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your great help! I really appreciate it!!